how to add infos to material with Unreal engine
In my application I receive materials info by network then I need to create a material with it. so far I create the material in the code bu I have no Idea about how to add roughness texture + intensity, metalness texure + intensity, normal map …
here is the code that I wrote create the material.
struct MaterialMetha
{
    bool side;
    bool transparent;
    float opacity;
    FString map;
    FColor color;
    FString roughnessMap;
    float roughness;
    FString metalnessMap ;
    float metalness;
    FString emissiveMap;
    FColor emissive;
    float emissiveIntensity;
    FString normalMap;
};

bool AShapeGenerator::GenerateMaterial(FString id, MaterialMetha metha)
{
    FString name = FString(TEXT("Material_")) + id;
    FString path = FString(TEXT("/Game/Material/Generated/"));
    FString packageName = path + name;

    UPackage * package = CreatePackage(*packageName);
    UMaterial* mat = NewObject<UMaterial>(package, FName(*name), RF_Public | RF_Standalone);

    mat->AddToRoot();
    #if WITH_EDITOR
        mat->PreEditChange(nullptr);
        mat->PostEditChange();
    #endif
    FAssetRegistryModule::AssetCreated(mat);
    package->FullyLoad();
    package->SetDirtyFlag(true);

    return true;
}

When I receive the material through the  network, it will appear in the editor with unreal default values. Now the question is what I want to do is fill it with the value from MaterialMetha structure,and I don't know where to find informations
Thanks for you time.

I'm sorry, but I don't think I understand what's your objective here.
What I got from this is that you are going to receive posts through an API with minimal structural information to create a new unreal engine Material so that, when the post is made, a routine can run to create a "replica" of the sent Material into your instance of the editor on the fly. If that's the point, my question is: why?
If the objective is just to share updated files, using a version control system wouldn't far more simple?

Yes you understood well. I create a material and it will be possible to use this material with static meshes. Now I already create the material but the problem is I don't know how to set normalmap, roughtness, ect. I can only provide partial code My company will not allow a git. Now I created a default material blueprint, and I can create an instance when needed and change base color, roughtness, metalness... in C++ using for example : matInstance->SetTextureParameterValue("EmissiveMap", textureEmit); . The question was more about how to create the first material without blueprint
